# how to format a number/date in play 2.0 template?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm struggling a bit with the play 2.0 templating system; I have a method that returns what in scala is an 'Int' and I want to format it using the pattern "#,###".

I have tried `@order.itemCount().format("#,###")` and `@( order.item.count() format "#,###" )` but no love.

I'm not sure if there's a trick to this in the play template syntax or whether I just need to learn how to do this in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward approach would be to use [Java's string formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
scala> val n = 1000000
n: Int = 1000000

scala> "%,d".format(n)
res0: String = 1,000,000
```

This will also handle localization correctly:

```
scala> String.format(java.util.Locale.ITALY, "%,d", n: java.lang.Integer)
res1: java.lang.String = 1.000.000
```

Comment: The syntax strikes me as a bit unnatural but it certainly does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Fine, but how do you get the right locale from within a template?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
<td>@("%.2f".formatLocal(lang().toLocale(), variable.getAverage()))</td>
```