# Format a double without decimals & adding commas for thousands in Scala Java Play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I have doubles such as:

`87654783927493.00`

`23648.00`

I want to output them as:

`87,654,783,927,493`

`23,648`

---

I found the following solution:

```
@("%,.2f".format(myDoubleHere).replace(".00",""))
```

This was with the help of:

[how to format a number/date in play 2.0 template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515123/how-to-format-a-number-date-in-play-2-0-template)

[What is the proper way to format a double in a Play 2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878747/what-is-the-proper-way-to-format-a-double-in-a-play-2-template)

---

I'd like to replace this shameless solution by something more clean. Chopping off those decimals using a `.replace()` method is really not pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "2" in `%,.2f` represents the number of decimals to use in the formatting.  You could just use `%,.0f` instead:

```
"%,.0f".format(myDoubleHere)
```

You can read more about Java formatting in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).  Your other option is to round to an `Int`, and then use `%,d`:

```
"%,d".format(math.round(myDoubleHere))
```

This might handle some edge cases better, depending on your use-case (e.g. `5.9` would become `6` and not `5`).

Answer (score 1):

Best understood through simple examples, use `%,d`:

```
scala> f"Correctly Formatted output using 'f': ${Int.MaxValue}%,d"
val res30: String = Correctly Formatted output using 'f': 2,147,483,647

scala> s"Incorrectly Formatted output using 's': ${Int.MaxValue}%,d"
val res31: String = Incorrectly Formatted output using 's': 2147483647%,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java `DecimalFormat` we have that

```
val df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###");
df: java.text.DecimalFormat = java.text.DecimalFormat@674dc
```

and so

```
scala> df.format(87654783927493.00)
res: String = 87,654,783,927,493

scala> df.format(23648.00)
res: String = 23,648
```

Answer (score 0):

For integers and floats this works for me in regular Scala:

```
// get java number formatters
val dformatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance
val fformatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance

val deciNum = 987654321
val floatNum = 12345678.01
printf("deciNum: %s\n",dformatter.format(deciNum))
printf("floatNum: %s\n",fformatter.format(floatNum))
```

And the output is:

```
deciNum: 987,654,321
floatNum: 12,345,678.01
```